# Load page content with AJAX after being gated

Tags: theming, ajax, 9

I need to gate a page's content with a form so that the content isn't loaded until a form on the frontend is filled out.

I can hook into this form's `onSuccess` method (all via JavaScript) but I'm a bit at a loss on how I'd functionally delay the loading of just the page content and insert it later.

So I'd essentially have an function for my form:

```
myForm.onSuccess( function() {
    // Load the body copy for this Drupal page
});
```

Is there a way I can halt the rendering of this region of the page but initiate that via an AJAX call after this form fill?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't do that really - even if you remove the page content with JS, it'll still be in the source. Your code won't run until the DOM is ready, so the content will appear and then disappear at a rate inline with the user's browser/connection speed. People without JS enabled will simply see the page as normal. To properly gate content you need to hook into the page build in PHP, check a cookie value and replace the content with a form if not present, then trigger the page cache kill switch. Your form submit handler will then set the cookie, and the rest takes care of itself

Comment: You might also need to add a cache context for the cookie to the node build you're altering